# Scala conversion of Strings

Tags: scala

When I run the following program :

```
object Problem {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val v = 53.toString
    val w = v(0).toInt
    println(w)
  }
}
```

it prints out `53`, instead of what I would have expected, `5`.  Can someone help me understand why?

**UPDATE**: The same thing happens if I use `charAt` instead of the array syntax

Answer (score 9, accepted):

53 is the ASCII value for the character '5'.  Try `63.toString` and you'll see 54 after `v(0).toInt`.

Use `.asDigit` to convert a `Char` to its `Int` value. In other words,  `'5'.toInt == 53` but `'5'.asDigit == 5`.

Answer (score 0):

> Your code prints 53 because 53 is the ASCII value for the character '5'.

You will need to make the following changes if you want to see `5` as an answer. Hope it helps to clarify.

```
//Using charAt() should work, and print `5` as expected.

object Problem {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val v = 53.toString
    val w = v.charAt(0)
    println(w)
  }
}


Similarly, removing the `toInt()` should also print '5'.

object Problem {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val v = 53.toString
    val w = v(0)
    print(w)
  }
}
```

Comment: The first example is not 5 because the ASCII value of 5 is 53. It is 5 because 5 is the first character in the string "53". ASCII values are irrelevant here.

Comment: you are right, edited now. Thanks michael-mior@.

Comment: The answer still states that the code prints 53 because 53 is the ASCII value for '5'.

Comment: right michael-mior@, but I was referring to the code from the question... I think now should clearer right?

Comment: The explanation is still incorrect though. The code printing 53 has nothing to do with ASCII values.

Comment: The first phrase of my answer is to answer the question posted here, which states the same thing as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480531/376382) @MichaelMior. Then the 2 examples I provide are 2 options where whoever asked this question can expected the answer to be 5.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted what you were intending to state at the beginning of the answer.